# MarkInfo and StructTreeRoot missing when generating PDF/A 1-a file in Latex

Tags: pdfx

I need to submit my thesis as a PDF/A 1-a file but I am having issues in generating the file from Latex. I have several problems (one with Transparencies) but I think the main issues go down to missing MarkInfo and StructTreeRoot. I have to admit that I am completely ignorant and I have no idea what they are.

I am using TexStudio and I tried compiling the file both with Latex and PDFLatex. I am following the [pfx package guide](http://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf) but I am getting the same problems when checking the file with two different sources.

With [3 heights PDF validator](https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx) I get:

- "The key MarkInfo is required but missing." and
- "The key StructTreeRoot is required but missing."

With Vera PDF checker I fail the following tests:

- "The document catalog dictionary shall include a MarkInfo dictionary with a Marked entry in it, whose value shall be true." and
- "The logical structure of the conforming file shall be described by a structure hierarchy rooted in the StructTreeRoot entry of the document catalog dictionary, as described in PDF Reference 9.6".

I reduced my code to a simple example:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{TEST_Meta.xmpdata}
    \Title{This is the title}
    \Author{Author ABC}
    \Language{en-US}
    \Keywords{Test \sep 123}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colorprofiles}
\usepackage[a-1a,mathxmp]{pdfx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=, bookmarks=true}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

I am just a test.

\end{document}
```

From what I understand, I miss to specify something in the metadata but, as I said, I have no idea what is missing since I am totally not familiar with this and after some googling I didn't find anything.

Do you have any clue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct option in the validator? Tagging is imho only required for the `-u` variants of the standards.  Beside this: pdfx doesn't tag a document, you need the (very experimental!!!) package tagpdf for this.

Comment: I am getting the same also when checking with Preflight in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC.
I get: "PDF document is not compliant with PDF/A-1a (2005).

- Structured PDF: Structure tree root entry missing

- MarkInfo missing"

Comment: sorry, mixed up the standards. Do you have to create 1a? Can't you do 1b or 2b?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to generate 1a. I think that 1b doesn't consider these issues since I can transform the PDF into 1b without errors.

Comment: well then your are bit out of luck -- even more if you want to use pdflatex, tagpdf works best with lualatex. We are working on tagging, but everything is still very experimental and incomplete. As you seem to have access to Acrobat, why don't you try to use it to convert your document?

Comment: Yeah I am not too lucky with this. I tried to use Acrobat to convert the document but I am getting the same issue that the structure tree root and the MarkInfo are missing.
Thanks four your help.

Comment: Well you could try tagpdf, it will add it. But I'm not quite sure how it behaves with pdfx.

Comment: I added:
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{activate-all}
and it worked with the simple case above. However, it doesn't fix all the issues with my real Latex file which includes way more stuff. I managed to solve most of the issues ("Transparencies") through Acrobat but I still have a problem. An online validation tool gives me "The key ToUnicode is required but missing." while another gives me the similar issue "The font dictionary shall include a ToUnicode entry whose value is a CMap stream object that maps character codes to Unicode values (...)". Do you have any idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: related question [Generate a PDF/A, level «a» and other standards compliant document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545903/creating-a-pdf-a-pdf-x-and-pdf-ua-multistandard-compliant-thesis-or-paper)