# lwarp to html issues with termcal

Tags: pdftex, html, accessibility, lwarp

I am trying to convert my LaTeX document into HTML for accessibility reasons.  Unfortunately, I have not found a package that correctly creates an accessible document (for images and tables), and so I was told to convert it to HTML, and that way, it can be accessible.  I have tried various techniques that are documented in the [Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39309/convert-latex-to-html) and found that `lwarp` has the best conversion to the display of my PDF output.  However, it seems that `lwarp` has an issue when using the package `termcal`.  After I compiled and ran the code `lwarpmk html`, I end up with an error `! Misplaced alignment tab character &. <inserted text> ...ut \scshape \centering Tuesday& \struct \scshape \centering...`. I have tried going into the code of `termcal` and based on the `lwarp` documentation enclosing the line of code in error with `\StartDefiningTabulars` and `\EndDefiningTabulars` did not work.  It did create an HTML document, but the calendar was missing.  Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

I am running the code on MacBook Pro 2019 using a program called Texpad with pdfLaTeX.

Below is my MWE from Brian Hall's sample syllabus that I have changed to use termcal:

```
% This syllabus template was created by:
% Brian R. Hall
% Associate Professor, Champlain College
% www.brianrhall.net

% Document settings
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lwarp}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[pdftex,                                     % For accessibility requirements
            pdftitle={CSCI 133 SPRING 2020},
            pdflang={en-GB}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{termcal} % Works with the calendar display
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

% Course information
\begin{tabular}{ l l }
  \multirow{3}{*}{%InsertImage
                 } 
  & \LARGE Course Code \\\\
  \mrowcell & \LARGE Course Title \\\\
  \mrowcell & \LARGE Day(s), Time, Place \\\\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{10mm}

\newpage

% Course Outline
\newcommand{\TRClass}{%
\skipday % Monday (no class)
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday} % Tuesday
\skipday % Wednesday (no class)
\calday[Thursday]{\classday} % Thursday
\skipday % Friday 
\skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
}

\newcommand{\Holiday}[2]{%
\options{#1}{\noclassday}
\caltext{#1}{#2}
}


\textbf {\large Tentative Course Outline}:

The weekly coverage might change as it depends on the progress of the class.  However, you must keep up with the reading assignments.

\begin{center}
\begin{calendar}{01/27/2020}{17} % Semester starts on 01/27/2020 and last for 17
                    % weeks, including finals week
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\TRClass
% schedule
\caltexton{1}{Intro to course and data structures}
\caltextnext{C++ review}
\caltextnext{C++ review, cont.}

% ... and so on

% Holidays
\Holiday{2/14/2020}{Lincoln's Birthday Holiday}
\Holiday{2/17/2020}{Presidents' Day Holiday}
\Holiday{4/6/2020}{Spring Break}
\Holiday{4/7/2020}{Spring Break}
\Holiday{4/8/2020}{Spring Break}
\Holiday{4/9/2020}{Spring Break}
\Holiday{4/10/2020}{Spring Break}

% ... and so on

%\options{12/11/2017}{\noclassday} % finals week
%\options{12/12/2017}{\noclassday} % finals week
%\options{12/13/2017}{\noclassday} % finals week
%\options{12/14/2017}{\noclassday} % finals week
%\options{12/15/2017}{\noclassday} % finals week



%\caltext{5/15/2017}{\textbf{Final Exam: 8:00am - 10:30am}}
\end{calendar}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can compile your document with TeX4ht (when I remove `lwarp` and explicit `pdftex` option for `hyperref`). It complains about `\mrowcell`, but so does `pdflatex`. The output seems OK.

Comment: @michal.h21 I tried again, and yes the output is ok.  I realized that the .css file kept the formating of it to look similar to the PDF output.  However, I will still prefer `lwarp` due to its accessible features.  Thank you for your comment and help.

Comment: Have you seen [Creating a PDF/A PDF/X and PDF/UA document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545903/creating-a-pdf-a-pdf-x-and-pdf-ua-multistandard-compliant-thesis-or-paper)? I do not like mass page-type invitations because I have to typwrite them first into my calendar. It's better to send Outlook invitations so they can go directly into your personal electronical calendar. This works for the blind the deaf the lazy and the forgetful.