# Benefit of PDF-A on ArXiv?

Tags: arxiv, pdf-a

I am wondering if it is beneficial to include `\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}` to the preamble when submitting articles to ArXiv? And if so, why is this not the standard - is there any disadvantage of PDF-As?

Comment: PDF/A-1b is very restrictive and makes even harder to get something (esp. with color) compiled on ArXiv. Also, since the source of your document will be archived on ArXiv, there is (probably) no need to compile it as PDF/A, where the A stands vor Archive

Comment: I'd be curious to know what sort of accessibility guarantees that using that package offers, as that's a major project for arXiv at the moment.

But I can confirm that `pdfx` is installed in the tex tree and does work with a MWE.

Comment: In our last round of testing this package, we discovered that it doesn't embed the colormaps in texlive 2020, so use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

Just including `\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}` in your preamble alone does not solve a problem. The `pdfx` package is outdated since a long time ago, I discourage it's usage.

There is however an advantage of creating PDF/A compatible documents since metadata is stored in a standardized machine readable format.

As of January 2024 it's still best to use the way I described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545903/creating-a-pdf-a-pdf-x-and-pdf-ua-multistandard-compliant-thesis-or-paper) to create a compatible document.

This may change soon as there is native support for tagged PDF in LaTeX under development.

The only disadvantage of PDF/A is it's increased file size. But nowadays a few dozens of kB do not matter much.

Comment: Indeed. Any PDF can be internally labeled as PDF/A (or PDF/X) but the label does not make it true. And, as you noted, package `pdfx` is outdated.